# repeat operation to different data set in R language

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set which have 5 columns (column, from 0 to 4) named as data1. I will add column 2, 3 together and normalize the result of data1. I will do the following :

```
final_data = my_norm_function(data1[2]+data1[3])
write.table(final_data)
```

But I want do the same operation to other data set, say `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, etc -- get two columns out from each data set and add them together, normalize the result and save. Is there any loop I can use to do this? Then I will get saved data set corresponding to `data1`, `data2`, `data3`.

Comment: One approach might be use `eapply` if you want apply the function to all objects in your working space or a specific environment.

Comment: You could store all your datasets as items in a list (`my_list <- list(data1, data2...)`) , then apply your function to each element in the list, either using `lapply` or just a `for` loop

Comment: I am doing this now. But I guess create a large list is less efficient? Say data1 have hundreds of columns and I only need to add column 2,3. We can just load 2,3 in to memory, can we?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's a `for` loop version:

```
for(i in c("vector of file names")){
   datain<-read.table(i)
   final_data = my_norm_function(datain[2]+datain[3])
   write.table(final_data,file=paste("final_data",i))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good way. But I have already loaded the data. So I do not want to loop the reading process which makes it slow. I already have dataset 1, dataset 2 in memory.

Comment: in that case, delete the read.table line and change the vector of file names to a vector of the names of the data.

Comment: Each loops give me a final column. I would like to append them. For example, first run gives me column1=[1],[2],[3] , then column2 = [4],[5],[6], I would like to save them in one csv table, with column 1=1,2,3, then column 2, 4,5,6 instead of individual files, how to cbind the columns in a for loop?Many thanks!